# Wordpress - Add custom quote author

Tags: wordpress

I want to create some quotes in my wordpress, but they always get the author "admin". Can I make the author like "Winston Churchill" ?

If so, can I add info about this author ? (like where he was born, etc.)

Comment: You might be best asking on wordpress.stackexchange.com. HTH.

Comment: How are you creating the quotes? Are you using a plugin? If so, then check if the plugin allows you to set the author when creating a new quote.

Comment: No, I just add a new Article as a Quote. I can add tags too, which is very useful

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say you need a separate page or link, upon clicking that you need to show the quotes of Churchill ?

If that is the case, you can very well create a page from selecting New -> Page from the Dashboard and put in whatever you wish to in that and after that select Appearance -> Menu and from the Menu select the page that you have used and drop it in the menu panel and save it. Refresh it, It should hopefully work.

Don't forget to set the Menu area.

Comment: this process would have to be automatic... for all the authors of the quotes I add

Comment: Once you have linked that page to the Menu, whatever you type in that page gets reflected automatically